# Routes React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I hava Routes like this:

```
export enum routes {
  PROFILE_SETTINGS = "/settings/profile",
  ACCOUNT_SETTINGS = "/settings/account",
  PASSWORD_CHANGE = "/settings/account/password",
  ACCOUNT_DELETE = "/settings/account/delete",
  EMAIL_CHANGE = "/settings/account/email",
  USER_COMMENTS = "/profile/:user/comments",
  USER_PRODUCTS = "/profile/:user/products",
}
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CommunicatorTemplate>
          <MainTemplate>
            <Switch>
              <ProfileTemplate>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.USER_COMMENTS}
                  component={UserComments}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.USER_PRODUCTS}
                  component={UserProducts}
                />
              </ProfileTemplate>
              <SettingsTemplate>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.PROFILE_SETTINGS}
                  component={ProfileSettings}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.ACCOUNT_SETTINGS}
                  component={AccountSettings}
                />
                <Route
                  path={routes.PASSWORD_CHANGE}
                  component={PasswordChange}
                />
                <Route path={routes.EMAIL_CHANGE} component={EmailChange} />
                <Route path={routes.ACCOUNT_DELETE} component={AccountDelete} />
              </SettingsTemplate>
            </Switch>
          </MainTemplate>
        </CommunicatorTemplate>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

And the problem is that when I go to any page which starts with `/settings` I am redirected to  the `Profile` page and not to f.e. `PROFILE_SETTINGS` or `ACCOUNT_SETTINGS`. I think the problem is with `/settings/profile` because it also get a `/profile` part, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to reproduce a more minimal example, so it's easier to isolate the issue

Comment: could you please put additional code that elaborate your Template components? and please provide the root of the app where router declared. maybe there is a loop in your components or something like that

Comment: This is the root. I don't think template code is useful, beacause is just something like: ```<Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>```.

Comment: I just added the whole root component

Comment: even if I remove routes from template, it is redirecting me to the profile template

Comment: I think that I can't use templates like this. Settings and Profile templates should be used in lower level, I mean inside components like AccountSettings or EmailChange

Comment: what I wrote in the previous comment, it works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that within the `Switch` component only `Route` or `Redirect` components are valid children. Recall that the `Switch` component renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location, but you've wrapped your routes inside either the `ProfileTemplate` or `SettingsTemplate`, and as such, only the `ProfileTemplate` is "matched" and rendered. The wrapped routes inside the wrapper are now just inclusively matched and rendered like the `Switch` wasn't there at all.

Wrap the wrappers in matching routes for them, and then also wrap the routes in a `Switch` so they are exclusively matched.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CommunicatorTemplate>
      <MainTemplate>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={[routes.USER_COMMENTS, routes.USER_PRODUCTS]}>
            <ProfileTemplate>
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.USER_COMMENTS}
                  component={UserComments}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.USER_PRODUCTS}
                  component={UserProducts}
                />
              </Switch>
            </ProfileTemplate>
          </Route>
          <Route
            path={[
              routes.PROFILE_SETTINGS,
              routes.ACCOUNT_SETTINGS,
              routes.PASSWORD_CHANGE,
              routes.EMAIL_CHANGE,
              routes.ACCOUNT_DELETE
            ]}
          >
            <SettingsTemplate>
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.PROFILE_SETTINGS}
                  component={ProfileSettings}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={routes.ACCOUNT_SETTINGS}
                  component={AccountSettings}
                />
                <Route
                  path={routes.PASSWORD_CHANGE}
                  component={PasswordChange}
                />
                <Route path={routes.EMAIL_CHANGE} component={EmailChange} />
                <Route path={routes.ACCOUNT_DELETE} component={AccountDelete} />
              </Switch>
            </SettingsTemplate>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </MainTemplate>
    </CommunicatorTemplate>
  </ThemeProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the exact from `Route`. so

```
<Route
    path={routes.PROFILE_SETTINGS}
    component={ProfileSettings}
    />
```

Comment: It is not it. ```/settings/profile``` return me profile site